# How can I remove the hair on the sensor from this picture?

Tags: post-processing, object-removal

[image]

There appears to be a hair on the image sensor that shows up in the upper left corner.  I tried dodging and tried using the clone heal tool.  Any better ideas?

update; this is my best work on the image so far

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Content aware patch or healing tools should do the job.   If you don't get good results, in the sky area, try using the brush, selecting some blue sky and painting over the hair first, *then* use the healing tools.  This is especially true near the edges of the image.

What specifically went wrong with your results?

Comment: what i have gotten no, the picture i updated with, is the best ive been able to do.  (new to lightroom). if you do 1:1 or especially 3:1, the repaired areas look terrible.  but on the screen, uncrooped i guess no one will notice.

Comment: Photoshop will do a much better job of it than Lightroom

Comment: yea i dont have photoshop; probably a good investment, but perhaps i should try to learn the same thing in GIMP?